# Excel Services Using SQL Server 2008R2 Refresh

Tags: excel

I have an excel file set up to pull data from SQL Server 2008R2. I can view it and refresh it fine locally in Excel 2010.

I upload it to SharePoint 2010 and can view the data in the spreadsheet in the browser using Excel Services. However, when I click to refresh the data in the spreadsheet in the browser (clicking Data > Refresh All), the data does not get refreshed. One thing to note is that when I do open up the excel spreadsheet in the browser it shows this message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had configured to pull SQL data through a "Table" view.  It needed to be set up to use a "Pivot Table" view.

Comment: please describe more about how this is configured by you... add a link or link to your blog ...